# What is the max char limit for the `text` parameter in Whatsapp send text URLs (mobile and web)?

Tags: whatsapp

How long can I make a whatsapp message when I'm sending it using the `whatsapp://send?text=` and `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=` URLs?

I know that the general URL size limit is 2048 characters, but does it also apply in this case?
Or is it lower/higher?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I played with this more and came to know a few more things. Below mentioned limit is probably limit of the windows command line argument system. This limit isn't applicable for web based whatsapp and only applicable for desktop app.

Original: For https://api.whatsapp.com thing there's a hard limit of 2057 characters for the whole URL meaning counting from https...

I checked it myself in Google Chrome. And if you are using non-ASCII characters then limit will be much less.

Comment: The previous post already answered the question and provides a valid source.

Comment: I figured it out using brute force. I tested various lengths of URLs to come to that number. For me it worked until the length was 2057 characters and if you put one more character it would stop working. It was a brute force experiment, How do I give source for this?

Answer (score 1):

A text message can be a max of **4096 characters** long.
Source: [WhatsApp API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/text)

Comment: But that's a restriction for the Business API, I wonder if the url one works same

Answer (score -1):

A text message can be a max of **4096 characters** long.
Source: [WhatsApp API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/text)

The complete code is below.
**Swift 5**

Please follow the below steps for sharing on WhatsApp through URL Schemes

1. Add this code in your app "info.plist"

```html
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

[image]

2. For sharing text and URL

**Code**

```
    @IBAction func whatsappShareText(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    
        let message = "First Whatsapp Share & https://www.google.co.in"
        var queryCharSet = NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        
        // if your text message contains special characters like **+ and &** then add this line
        queryCharSet.remove(charactersIn: "+&")
        
        if let escapedString = message.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: queryCharSet) {
            if let whatsappURL = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(escapedString)") {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [: ], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    debugPrint("please install WhatsApp")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: This seems to be out of date. The correct answer is below
 Facebook API says 4096 chars

Comment: @CaptainCrunch the previous answer was as per APIS's documentation of that time.
 seems like they have updated the APIs characters limit later on so updating the answer.